# SQL Query Count - Join two tables and get a count even if it is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

Ok, working on a query in SQL 2012 right now to join two tables and get a count.  The count is how many companies are associated with a primary company.  This lists exists in the same table, Contact, and they are all connected as ID of the primary company is listed in the secondary company as CompanyID.  I can get a count if the primary has at least 1 secondary but I can't seem to get a count if the primary has no secondary and I need to show that 0 value.  Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Company, c.Category, COUNT(c1.ID) AS Secondaries
FROM Contact AS c INNER JOIN Contact AS c1 ON c.ID = c1.CompanyId
WHERE (c.MemberType = 'ORG_M') AND (c1.MemberType = 'ORG_M')
GROUP BY c.ID, c.Company, c.Category
```

When I do this, I get this information back:

```
ID  Company       Category      Count
1   Company 1     RS_1          1
2   Company 2     RS_1          1
3   Company 3     RS_1          1
4   Company 4     RS_1          1
```

What I am missing is the 0 value for if a company exists in the company table but has no secondary company tied to them.  How do I get that?

Comment: Changing the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` should cover it.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `outer join` instead and move the `where` criteria to the `join`:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Company, c.Category, COUNT(c1.ID) AS Secondaries
FROM Contact AS c
    LEFT JOIN Contact AS c1 ON c.ID = c1.CompanyId AND c1.MemberType = 'ORG_M'
WHERE c.MemberType = 'ORG_M'
GROUP BY c.ID, c.Company, c.Category
```

Comment: This might work too... it's been a while since I've used SQL Server. Will the COUNT(c1.ID) evaluate to 0 if there are no records in the outer table?

Comment: @evanv -- that is correct -- here's a simple fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea8147/1 -- Also, please note in your answer, you need to move `c1.MemberType = 'ORG_M'` to the `join` instead of the `where` criteria.  As is, it will negate the `outer join`.

Comment: Agreed then. I'll make the change in mine.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried a left join but never thought to move the c1 where to the join statement.  This seems to have worked now.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon on this.  Before I made this change, I was pulling 396 records but it was only of records who had secondaries as the ones who didn't were ignored as it was considered a null value.  

Now that I have made this change, I am up to over 4000 records but the problem is that this is picking up secondaries who don't have companies tied to them.  These secondaries that are now coming up should be in the count under the original primary company(which they are) but are now being counted again.  Any idea on how to strip this part out?